# Function about math formulas

Tags: math, graphics, language-agnostic, charts, physics

I got decent programming experience, but I'm bad at math so I need a little help about these formulas.

[image]

The language doesn't really matter, but I need to figure out how I can create formulas by such graphics. I have a car that moves, and I need it to move smoothly. My goal is the following:

```
double acceleration(double x)
{
 //math formulas and so on
 return y;
}
```

when calling:

```
acceleration(140) // should return ~1
acceleration(20) // should return 0.2
acceleration(40) // should return 0.6
acceleration(100) // 0.8
acceleration(160) // ~1
acceleration(180) // ~0.6
```

and so on..

I drew this, but I want to create a function based on this graphic. Any resources/examples will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use piecewise linear approximation to your graph.

Comment: Piecewise linear is not smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to read about polynomial fitting of functions.  You've got eight points that I can see - the six you posted plus zero acceleration at time 0 and 200.  It'll be easy to fit a polynomial to those points and approximate that curve.

A [Lagrangian approach](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13151-lagrange-interpolator-polynomial/content/lagrangepoly/html/demo_lagrangepoly.html) would be easy.  Look into others if you have requirements continuity that you'd like to enforce as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) produces nice, smooth, piecewise-polynomial curves that are usually used for this kind of thing. They are usually implemented in libraries. If you use Java you could use [`SplineInterpolator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html) from Apache Commons Math for this.

Splines are preferred to plain polynomials because the avoid the wild oscillation at the edges of the interpolated interval ([Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)).

Another option is fitting a low-degree polynomial to your data. From your graph it looks like a 4th degree polynomial would be enough. You don't have as much control over the curve as with splines though.